# UV unwrap, tick box: Use subdivision surface

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

A quick question,

When I UV unwrap, I can choose "Use subdivision surface." in the box

I'm using Subdivision Surface (which I haven't applied to the model).

I don't understand what it does. But the result is better.

[image]

Comment: As stated in the manual : "Map UVs taking vertex position after Subdivision Surface Modifier into account." https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/mapping_types.html

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning

Comment: @N03 I'll prepare an answer to show it.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain what this means: let's say I have this not so great model which is quite low poly and I have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on it to make it more smooth. I also put some seams on it for UV unwrapping. I just focus on the faces of this one side view to show the effect.

If I simply unwrap it without the *Use Subdivision Surface* option, the unwrapped faces are shaped more or less like the original low poly mesh:

[image: low poly uvs]

But if you enable the option, the UV unwrapping will take the change of the overall shape due to the *Subdivision Surface* modifier into account. Of course the UVs still just have the low poly mesh so they are not as rounded as the subdivided version, but they are matching a bit more (here I have enabled to show the effect of the modifier in *Edit Mode* so that you can see the deformation better):

[image: with subdivided mesh]

Below I have traced the outlines of the UVs and laid them over the model to show the difference better. What this can be useful for is take into account that textures that use the UV map to be placed on an object are less distorted when the *Subdivision Surface* modifier smoothes the mesh. When the mesh is not so extremely low poly, the result might be even better.

If in the example below when you place a logo or text etc. on the side of the object mapped to the left UVs, then the result on the subdivided object will be squashed more than when using the UVs on the right.

[image: comparison with and without subdiv]

How much this option has an effect on the UV map, how good or bad the result for your model will be etc. of course depends a lot on the model itself, the unwrapping process, the seams, just like normal unwrapping there are a lot of variables taken into account when it comes to good or bad UV texturing.

Another example, this time comparing the effect of *Use Subdivision Surface* with some logo on the side of the object. While on the left without the option enabled, the logo is squashed vertically (the yellow part is supposed to the a circle), it looks a lot better on the right although not perfect due to the very low poly base mesh.

[image: logo comparison]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I feel like I've got a solid grasp now! :)

Comment: @N03 I just added a "real" example with a texture at the end to show (one of) the uses cases for this. Basically you can of course tweak UVs manually to reduce the distortion of textures, but this option helps reducing the need to or the amount of work manually.